# Vue leaflet open popup when loaded

Tags: vue.js, leaflet

How can I make Vue-leaflet marker popup to be already open when loaded.

```
<l-map style="height: 350px" :zoom="zoom" :center="center">
  <l-tile-layer :url="url"></l-tile-layer>
  <l-marker :lat-lng="markerLatLng">
    <l-popup>Hello!</l-popup>
  </l-marker>
</l-map>
```

I have tried adding options like this

`<l-popup :options="{closeOnClick: false,autoClose: false, openPopup:true}">Hello!</l-popup>`

but it's not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no property in Vue Leaflet which allows a `popup` to be open by default. To open a `popup` programmatically, we need to ref the parent/activator `marker` component of the `popup`.

Let's say below is your template markup

```
<template>
  <l-map 
    style="height: 350px" 
    :zoom="zoom" 
    :center="center">
    <l-tile-layer :url="url"></l-tile-layer>
    <l-marker ref="marker" :lat-lng="markerLatLng">
      <l-popup ref="popup">
        This is a popup open by default
      </l-popup>
    </l-marker>
  </l-map>
</template>
```

Then, you can write this `mounted` lifecycle method to open popup programmatically when it has been loaded.

```
mounted(){
   this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.$refs.marker.mapObject.openPopup()
   }) 
  }
```

A working example of this problem can be seen in `App.vue` file of my sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-leaflet-popup-open-by-default-09fcr

Answer (score 1):

thanks to aby.js.

I want to add the following to his answer:

**use @ready event** instead of mounted!

```
<l-map @ready="ready">
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just stumbled across this issue and if you are using Vue.js 3.x, `mapObject` was replaced by `leafletObject`:

```html
<l-marker v-for="{ id, markerCoordinate } of id"
  :ref="`marker${id}`" :lat-lng="markerCoordinate">
    <l-popup>

    </l-popup>
</l-marker>
```

```js
this.$refs[`marker${id}`][0].leafletObject.openPopup()
```